# Compiling Haskell package using c++ and stack/cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

There's a package clipper http://hackage.haskell.org/package/clipper that I want to use to detect intersection of complex polygons. It's an FFI to a C++ package. It works fine if you run

`cabal build --with-gcc=/usr/bin/g++`

but not otherwise. Is there some way to put that gcc option into the cabal file or otherwise get my stack project to build the dependency with g++?

Setting the $PATH for some reason doesn't work:

```
%  cabal build --with-gcc=g++
Building clipper-0.0.1...
Preprocessing library clipper-0.0.1...
[1 of 1] Compiling Algebra.Clipper  ( dist/build/Algebra/Clipper.hs, dist/build/Algebra/Clipper.o )
In-place registering clipper-0.0.1...

%  PATH=$(pwd):$PATH gcc
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

%  PATH=$(pwd):$PATH cabal build 
Building clipper-0.0.1...
Preprocessing library clipper-0.0.1...
In file included from Clipper.hsc:27:0:
cbits/clipper.hpp:29:18: fatal error: vector: Dosiero aŭ dosierujo ne ekzistas
compilation terminated.
compiling dist/build/Algebra/Clipper_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
command was: /usr/bin/gcc -c dist/build/Algebra/Clipper_hsc_make.c -o dist/build/Algebra/Clipper_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=710 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS=1 -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH=1 -Dlinux_HOST_OS=1 -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH=1 -Icbits -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/ghc-7.10.2/base_GDytRqRVSUX7zckgKqJjgw/include -I/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/ghc-7.10.2/integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS/include -I/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include -I/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.10.2-x86_64/lib/ghc-7.10.2/include/
```

Similarly, changing the Setup.hs as proposed by the @ErikR below didn't help.

```
% runghc Setup.hs build
"Hello, I am running"
fomg
BuildFlags
  { buildProgramPaths = []
  , buildProgramArgs = []
  , buildDistPref = Flag "dist"
  , buildVerbosity = Flag Normal
  , buildNumJobs = NoFlag
  , buildArgs = []
 }
fimg
BuildFlags
  { buildProgramPaths = [ ( "gcc" , "/usr/bin/g++" ) ]
  , buildProgramArgs = []
  , buildDistPref = Flag "dist"
  , buildVerbosity = Flag Normal
  , buildNumJobs = NoFlag
  , buildArgs = []
  }
Building clipper-0.0.1...
Preprocessing library clipper-0.0.1...
In file included from Clipper.hsc:27:0:
(etc)
```

Note that it crashes at the buildHook line, so in order to get the flags printed I needed to change the order around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simpler custom Setup.hs file:

```
import Distribution.Simple
import System.Environment

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  defaultMainArgs $ ["--with-gcc=c++"] ++ args
```

**Original Answer**

Some ideas:

(1) Create a wrapper script called `gcc` which invokes `g++`. Put the script early in your PATH so that running `gcc` will run your script instead of the real `gcc`. Perhaps you have this wrapper script in place only when you are building the clipper package.

(2) Write a custom Setup.hs.

1. Modify the `build-type` field in the clipper.cabal file to be `Custom` instead of `Simple`
2. Replace the Setup.hs file with:

   ```
   import Distribution.Simple
   import Distribution.Simple.Setup
   import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
   import Distribution.PackageDescription
   import Text.Show.Pretty

   main = do
     let hooks = simpleUserHooks

         myBuild :: PackageDescription -> LocalBuildInfo -> UserHooks -> BuildFlags -> IO ()
         myBuild pkgd buildinfo uhooks flags = do
           putStrLn $ ppShow flags
           let flags' = flags { buildProgramPaths = [("gcc","g++")] ++ (buildProgramPaths flags) }
           buildHook hooks pkgd buildinfo uhooks flags'
           putStrLn $ ppShow flags'
         hooks' = hooks { buildHook = myBuild }

     defaultMainWithHooks hooks'
   ```

Note: The import of Text.Show.Pretty is not necessary, so you can remove it and the ppShow calls if you don't have it installed.

The above Setup.hs should have the same effect as calling cabal with `--with-gcc=g++`.

Comment: Unfortunately your solutions didn't work. I've added some comments to my question to describe my experience.